# What does '{I gave one to} [the] both of you' mean?

Tags: grammar, idioms

How does one reflect the difference in meaning between 'I gave one to both of you' meaning you gave one to each of them, and 'I gave one to both of you' meaning you gave one item for the two to share?

When, if ever, is the term 'the both of you' relevant?

Comment: if you gave one to each you would say "i gave one to each of you"

Comment: You might also say 'I gave one to both of you'. Many people do.

Comment: you're right, and can also be extended to "to all of you". additionally, there seems to be an interesting [shift](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+each+of+you%2Cto+both+of+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20each%20of%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20both%20of%20you%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I gave one each to both of you.

Comment: Depends on the context.  You should know that this can't be answered with any confidence without more context than you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to say that you gave one to each person is "I gave one to each of you". Saying "I gave one to both of you" really means that one item is being shared between two people. Contextually though, if you prefer to say "both of you" it is possible to convey how many items were given through the surrounding context.

"The both of you" is a more collective expression, usually used to group two people together as one entity, often in anger. eg "There will be a scolding given to the both of you".

Comment: Very well expressed.

Comment: +1 But I would say *clearer* rather than *correct*. There are times when *both* can unambiguously mean *each*. *I gave a kiss to both of them* and *Both of you, go to your rooms!*

Comment: A valid point, I guess when it is something that clearly can't be split (a kiss) it would imply each. I think your second example groups them together, so does not mean each.

Comment: Please add supporting evidence for your claim 'Saying "I gave one to both of you" really means that one item is being shared between two people.' As it stands, this looks to be opinion rather than accepted usage.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually never correct to say, "the both of you" This is colloquial, from spoken Irish and Scottish and therefore, to be correct, you should say, "the both of yous"!  However, it is colloquial and should only be used in very informal speech. "Yous" is (very informal and in speech only) Scottish/Irish plural of, "you".

Comment: It sounds reasonably accurate to me.

Comment: Please add supporting references as already requested.

Comment: [This blog](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2009/08/bigger-than-the-both-of-us.html) supports the post (citing the OED), I have not been able to verify their citation though, nor have I found any other reference in support of this answer.